# Imagenes rotas al mostrar

Tags: php, javascript

Hola buenas tardes alguien me podria decir porque se muestran rotas algunas imagenes pero otras no [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi ajax

```
$('#cargueArchivo').click(function(){
    if($('#imagen').val() != "") {
    var archivo = $('#imagen')[0].files[0];
    var nombre = archivo.name;
    var tipo = $('#imagen').val().substring($('#imagen').val().lastIndexOf(".") + 1).toLowerCase();
    var tamano = archivo.size;

    if(tipo == "jpg" || tipo == "png" || tipo == "gif") {
        if(tamano < 5242880) {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('archivo',archivo);
            formData.append('nombre',nombre);
            var urlImagen = "" + nombre;


            $.ajax({
                url:'php/dataBase.php',
                type:'POST',
                cache:false,
                data:{action:"guardarRegistro",imagen:urlImagen,imagenText:$("#image_text").val()}

            }).done(function(response) {
                if(response == -1) {
                    alert("No es posible guardar la imagen en estos momentos. Por favor, inténtelo más tarde.");
                } else {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'php/upload.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false

                    }).done(function(response) {

                        if(response == -1) {
                            alert("No es posible subir la imagen en este momento. Por favor, actualizar imagen más tarde.");
                        } else {

                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        } else {
            alert("El tamaño de la imagen no debe exceder de 1 MB.");
        }
    } else {
        alert("El tipo de la imagen no es permitido. Tipos permitidos: .jpg, .png, .gif.");
    }

} else {
    alert("Por favor, seleccione una imagen.");
}



$.post("php/imagen_actualiza.php", function(data){
    $(".showImage").html(data);
});
```

Comment: Probaste dar `click derecho` sobre alguna imagen "rota" y `inspeccionar` así puedes ver la url que le esta asignando, es un modo de depurar

Comment: si amigo y se encuentra en la carpeta de files

Comment: intenta acceder directamente al elemento desde esa url, si te funciona debes verificar que el elemento `img` se refresque, si no esta funcionando es que la ruta esta mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que en la **Base de Datos** tienes un nombre de la imagen muy diferente al que tienes en tu carpeta de imágenes, es decir en tu base de datos tienes la imagen con el nombre **error2.png** pero en realidad se llama **030102018155510error2.png** y al traer los nombre de tus imagenes a través del **ajax** te arroja un **404** por ese mismo motivo porque no existe con ese nombre.

**Razones:**

**1)** Alguien a parte de ti o tu mismo cambiastes el nombre de la imagen en la BD a mano.

**2)** Antes no tenias la funcionalidad de agregar esa especie de **hash** adelante del nombre de la imagen y tienes data vieja con data nueva y por eso algunas se te ven y otras no.